# Using a dynamic lookup hash with strings and %

Tags: ruby, string, hash

Ruby's `%` formatting operator allows a hash to be used to substitute template values:

```
"%{a}" % { a: "banana" } # => "banana"
```

However, this doesn't work for dynamic hashes:

```
"%{a}" % Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "banana" } # => KeyError
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Edit: The X to this Y is creating a format hash from an array of possible values for each key. My current solution is something like this:

```
content = Hash[CONTENT.map { |k, v| [k, v.sample] }]
```

However, I think this is pretty ugly and would be nicer as a dynamic solution.

Comment: A Hash with a default value proc really only produces results in the `#[]` case; `hsh.fetch?("a") => KeyError` even with a default proc.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Doesn't matter, `String#%` doesn't use `Hash#fetch` so you can't even monkey patch your way around the nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want, at least not with MRI.

If you trace through the code, you'll find that `String#%` ends up implemented in C in `sprintf.c`. The `%{x}` handling part of the C implementation [does this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/sprintf.c#L611):

```
if (sym != Qnil) nextvalue = rb_hash_lookup2(hash, sym, Qundef);
if (nextvalue == Qundef) {
    rb_enc_raise(enc, rb_eKeyError, "key%.*s not found", len, start);
}
```

The `rb_hash_lookup2` call is used to get the value of the `sym` key from `hash` and then a `KeyError` is raised if `rb_hash_lookup2` doesn't find anything (i.e. `rb_hash_lookup2` returns `Qundef`). Now if we look at [`rb_hash_lookup2`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/hash.c#L756), we'll see that it explicitly doesn't use the Hash's default value:

```
VALUE
rb_hash_lookup2(VALUE hash, VALUE key, VALUE def)
{
    st_data_t val;

    if (!RHASH(hash)->ntbl || !st_lookup(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, &val)) {
        return def; /* without Hash#default */
    }
    return (VALUE)val;
}
```

Note that it uses the `def` argument rather than the Hash's default if it can't find the key:

```
return def; /* without Hash#default */
```

If you look at the [`Hash#[]` implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/hash.c#L745) you'll see that the only difference between it and `rb_hash_lookup2` is that `return def;` is replaced with:

```
return hash_default_value(hash, key);
```

There's your problem: `String#%` explicitly bypasses your Hash's default value logic. And since all this is happening with direct C calls you can't fetch monkey patch `Hash#[]`, `Hash#fetch`, `Hash#has_key?`, or anything else; similarly, you can't even subclass Hash and override any methods to kludge around `String#%`'s brain damage.

I think your ugly solution is less ugly than the alternatives (reimplementing `String#%`, hacking up a mess of regexes, ...).

YMMV with other Ruby implementations of course.

Comment: Yeah, this is the conclusion I came to while chatting on #ruby. The consensus there is that this behavior could be improved by doing the lookup with `rb_hash_aref` and then falling back to `rb_hash_lookup2` when the default value is `nil`. That would preserve both the current behavior for non-existent keys and get me the dynamic lookups I want.

Comment: Unfortunately that would require modifying the C source and recompiling your own binary (or waiting for the official MRI to implement that change).

Comment: Indeed, I'm creating a patch for it and I'll introduce it as a question on the ruby mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hash#values_at to explicitly initialize keys for the string, but it's kind of a hack:

```
"%{a}, %{b}" % Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = "banana" }.tap {|h| h.values_at(:a, :b) }
```

Comment: But that requires either knowing the string in advance or parsing the string.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work in my case. The string isn't known in advance, unfortunately.